# Validation for not storing the null values in database from activity

Tags: android

My activity has 3 edittext and a button.

I am **storing the values in the database**. When I am not inserting any value in the the edittext it should not enter the null values instead it should give some alert for that but in my program it accepts the null value also.

**How to handle this validation?**

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve your problem?

Comment: what u have tried ? you can put validations on EditText for null check using `String.Trim()`,`String.isEmpty()`,`String.length()` methods of String class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar to the below for all edittexts should work

```
String validString = editTextField.getText().toString();
if(validString.trim().equals("")){
   //put your alert here
}else{
   //write to DB
}
```

Comment: how to check for integer values?

Comment: Several options for that - one is to use the String.matches() method with a regular expression string as the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Just check the length of text in each EditText.

```
 if(input.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 ){

 }
```